# Access route data in FluentValidation for WebApi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I have a basic C# Web Api 2 controller that has a POST method to create an entity

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserModel userModel){ ... }
```

And also a PUT method to update said model

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UserModel userModel) { ... }
```

And here is the UserModel

```
public class UserModel
{
    public virtual Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Username { get; set; }
}
```

For my validator, I want to validate that the name is not taken on Post - easy enough.  For PUT, I need to validate that the name is not taken, by another user, but of course this particular user would have the same username.

```
public class UserModelValidator : AbstractValidator<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.Username)
            .Must(NotDuplicateName).WithMessage("The username is taken");

    }

    private bool NotDuplicateName(string username)
    {
        var isValid = false;

        //Access repository and check to see if username is not in use
        //If it is in use by this user, then it is ok - but user ID is
        //in the route parameter and not in the model.  How do I access?

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

I am using AutoFac, so maybe there is a way to inject the HttpRequest into the validator and get the route data that way.

Or possibly I could create a model binder that looks for the route data and adds it to the model?

Or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4):

I have found an other solution with inject the `IActionContextAccessor` into the Validator. With this I can access the ROUTE paramerter without the need of a special model binding.

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

*UserModelValidator.cs*

```
public class UserModelValidator : AbstractValidator<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelValidator(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.Username)
            .MustAsync(async (context, username, propertyValidatorContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                var userId = (string)actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values
                .Where(o => o.Key == "userId")
                .Select(o => o.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();

                return true;
            });
    }
}
```

**Update 2022 / FluentValidation 11**

> Starting in FluentValidation 11.0, validators that contain asynchronous rules will now throw a AsyncValidatorInvokedSynchronouslyException

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-11.html#sync-over-async-now-throws-an-exception

*UserModelValidator.cs*

```
public class UserModelValidator : AbstractValidator<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelValidator(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.Username)
            .Must((context, username, propertyValidatorContext) =>
            {
                var userId = (string)actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values
                .GetValueOrDefault("userId");

                return true;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks!
Just as small improvement:
`var userId = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext?.RouteData.Values.GetValueOrDefault("userId");`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of course is to add the `Id` to the `UserModel`. You'd have to add some extra checking on the `Post` and `Put` operations though. The first should ignore the `Id` when a client provides it. The second could check whether the `Id` in the path is the same as the `Id` in the model. If not, then return a `BadRequest`.

Altered model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public virtual Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Username { get; set; }
}
```

Altered methods:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserModel userModel)
{
   // ignore provided userModel.Id
}

public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UserModel userModel)
{
   if(id != userModel.Id)
   {
       // return bad request response
   }
}
```

**Update**

Having an Id in the route as well as in the model does indeed allow for a discrepancy between the two as you commented. A respectful API consumer will probably not post a request with misaligned Ids. But a malicious consumer (aka hacker) most probably will. Therefore you should return `BadRequest` when the Ids don't match.

You certainly do not want to update the `UserModel` with the Id as you mentioned otherwise you might end up with user 1 (the one in the url) overwritten by the details of user 2 (the one in the `UserModel`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that allows a discrepancy between the resource (the URL) and the model.  Also, at the moment the FluentValidators fire, they only have access to the model.  I did end up adding the Id to the UserModel, but also added an ActionFilter that updates the Id in UserModel to the id passed in via the URL.

Comment: I added an explanation in reply to your comment.

Comment: Thanks -- yes you are probably right that it should return BadRequest - the Id in the model is not a valid parameter for a put request (from the clients perspective) and is only used on the back-end, but it might make sense to return a BadRequest.

Comment: @Shibbz could You please show how You created that action filter? I'd trying to do same thing (access route data) and Your suggestion might work for me

Comment: @Misiu sure, [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/aschaible/4946f15486c7f7cc066beb29607b2c86).  Code could probably be cleaned up

Comment: @Shibbz thank You for sharing Your code, mine is very similar. Unfortunately I've noticed that Model is updated after FluentValidation validates it. Does it work same way in Youe code? Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932102/fluentvalidation-and-actionfilterattribute-update-model-before-it-is-validated

Comment: @Misiu yes .. here are a few gists:  [OrderedFilterInfo.cs](https://gist.github.com/aschaible/96809a3ba31ef1b049fec4513dffc9ae), [IOrderedFilterAttribute.cs](https://gist.github.com/aschaible/d9ce60311e8090a947d420f5826d2362), [OrderedFilterProvider.cs](https://gist.github.com/aschaible/32ac79febd2184e0bad7cf0d5f9a3fc5), [BaseActionFilterAttribute](https://gist.github.com/aschaible/7672b7662a5cebb354f57a97f4b6ba19).  Then add this: `webApiConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), new OrderedFilterProvider());`  Some of this is for Autofac, season to taste.

Comment: @Shibbz thank You for reply. If You could please write answer below my question, it would be easier to find for others, I'll check that right away and if everything will work I'll set Your answer as correct.

Comment: @Shibbz one more question - I'm enabling FluentValidation globally in Startup.cs, will Your method of ordering ActionFIlter work in my case?

Comment: @Misiu Can you show the way you enabled fluent validation with a post/comment in the other thread?